# Python user defined modules where to import system modules

Tags: python, module

I have created a module: `test.py`. Inside it looks like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   
N = 5
def test_img(data_loc):
    #F = load images from data_loc

    def plot_img(im):
        # a bunch of other codes
        plt.imshow(im)

    for i in range(N):
        plot_img(F(i))
```

(1) To use it somewhere as `import test` or `from test import test_img`, where do I `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`? Is it inside `test.py` like it is now?

(2) Does it matter `plot_img` is nested inside `test_img` in this case, if it is only going to be used inside `test_img`?

(3) Does it matter where do I declare constant `N` (This is an example, I have a lot of constants)? What if it is used inside `plot_img`, where do I declare it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, you can import matplotlib as you are.
2. It should work fine.
3. Put your constants wherever they are used.  If they're only used in one function, consider putting them inside it.  But what you have now is OK.